# How do I set child state with stateParam in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have been struggling for sometime for following scenario to work right. 
I am using ui-router with angularjs and I need something like:

Parent state : .state('parent', { url: '/parent/:someUserId' }

Child state as : .state('parent.child', { url: '/child' }

My requirement is child state should take route such as 'parent/:someUserId/child'

How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: That looks like it should work as-is, based on your explanation. Maybe try posting a plunkr that demonstrates the issue, and explaining what is or isn't supposed to happen.

Answer (score 2):

It should be simple as this:

```
        state('parent', {
            url: "/parent/:someUserId",
            templateUrl: "parent.html"
        }).
        state('parent.child', {
            url: "/todo",
            templateUrl: "parent/child.html"
        }).
```

reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router